# Solve the PDE : $z(p^2-q^2)=x-y$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

We have to find complete integral.
I am finding difficulty in converting it into a equation not involving $z$.
I tried solving it using charpit method but I got stuck.

Comment: Hi vivek, it is not entirely clear to me what the equation is. You call it a pde (partial differential equation) but I do not see any differential operators. Can you be more explicit about them?

Comment: P and q are differential operator.

Comment: P=dz/dx and q=dz/dy

Comment: Then you should write it that way to invite better answers. Do I understand that the equation is looking for unknown functions $z(x,y)$ satisfying $z(x,y).\left(\frac{\partial^2z}{\partial x^2}-\frac{\partial^2z}{\partial y^2}\right)=x-y$ ?

Comment: Yes..it may involve arbitrary constants

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Let $\begin{cases}u=x+y\\v=x-y\end{cases}$ ,

Then $\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial x}=\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial u}\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}+\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial v}\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial x}=\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial u}+\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial v}$

$\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial y}=\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial u}\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y}+\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial v}\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial y}=\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial u}-\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial v}$

$\therefore z\left(\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial x}+\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial y}\right)\left(\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial x}-\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial y}\right)=x-y$

$4z\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial u}\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial v}=v$

Let $z=w^\frac{2}{3}$ ,

Then $\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial u}=\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial w}\dfrac{\partial w}{\partial u}=\dfrac{2}{3w^\frac{1}{3}}\dfrac{\partial w}{\partial u}$

$\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial v}=\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial w}\dfrac{\partial w}{\partial v}=\dfrac{2}{3w^\frac{1}{3}}\dfrac{\partial w}{\partial v}$

$\therefore4w^\frac{2}{3}\dfrac{2}{3w^\frac{1}{3}}\dfrac{\partial w}{\partial u}\dfrac{2}{3w^\frac{1}{3}}\dfrac{\partial w}{\partial v}=v$

$\dfrac{\partial w}{\partial u}\dfrac{\partial w}{\partial v}=\dfrac{9v}{16}$

It belongs to a PDE of the form http://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/en/solutions/fpde/fpde3318.pdf.

Answer (score 0):

In order to find a complete integral of the PDE
$$
z(p^2-q^2)=x-y, \tag{1}
$$
let's substitute in $(1)$ the ansatz $z=f(\xi)$, where $\xi:=g(x)+g(y)$:
$$
f(\xi)[(g'(x))^2-(g'(y))^2](f'(\xi))^2=x-y. \tag{2}
$$
Choosing $g(t)=\frac{2}{3}(t+a)^{3/2}$, we have
$(g'(x))^2-(g'(y))^2=x-y,$ so Eq. $(2)$ simplifies to
$$
f(\xi)(f'(\xi))^2=1 \implies f(\xi)=\left(\frac{3}{2}\xi+b\right)^{2/3}. \tag{3}
$$
Combining $(3)$ with the definitions of $\xi$ and $g$, we finally obtain
$$
z(x,y)=\left[(x+a)^{3/2}+(y+a)^{3/2}+b\right]^{2/3} \qquad(x,y\geq -a). \tag{4}
$$